# Error while installing Visual studio 2005 in Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I have tried to installed Visual Studio 2008 and Sql Server 2005 on windows 7 & following is the result.

SQL SERVER 2005 :- Installed correctly without any error, but when I opened Management studio, it is not showing any server name, I tried to put systemName , systemName/Sqlexpress.

Visual Studio 2008: After 8-9 minute of successful installation , I received a error in installing & I had no more option other than closing the installer window.

I really don't have any idea about installing it in Windows 7.
Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get with VS2008?

Comment: Do the windows event logs provide any information?

Comment: I received a error message that system has some compatibility issues and VS can't be installed.
With SQL Server it is installed flawless but I am not able to open it.

Comment: I am getting a message that "This is not the genuie copy of Windows 7, please take backup of your data and upgrade it.". Is this the cause of the error?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3075/how-to-upgrade-the-windows-7-rc-to-rtm/

http://www.tutorialswindows7.com/how_to_activate_windows_7_home_premium.htm

What about these links ???

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite - With regards to the "This is not a genuine copy of Windows 7" message, is your Windows installation acivated? This error can be seen seen when using an invalid key, or when activation fails due to too many activations.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite - Are you using 32-bit of 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate? And can you clarify which version of VS you're installing - the title says 2005 but your post says 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when trying to upgrade from VS2005 to VS2008.
These problems normally happen because a previous Visual Studio version was not totally uninstalled.

You will not be able to install or uninstall any VS version until you completely erase all traces of this previous version. However, completely uninstalling VS is a very difficult exercise.

Here are some articles that contain methods of uninstalling VS.
Just follow all the advice and execute all the instructions, even if it seems that some of them might not pertain to your case.

[How to remove Visual Studio 2005](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907965)
[Uninstall Visual Studio (All Versions)](http://www.squidoo.com/uninstallvisualstudio)
[How To Manually Uninstall Visual Studio with MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246604%28VS.80%29.aspx)

**EDIT**

[Solutions for "This copy of Windows 7 is not genuine" problem](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/windows-7-activation-this-copy-of-windows-is-not-genuine.aspx)

You need to solve this problem before installing VS2008.
The above article lists three ways of doing so:

- Trying once more your Windows 7 Product Key.
- Using MGA Diagnostic Tool to resolve the problem.
- Activate Windows 7 using Phone.

The last method is required, if by any chance your Windows 7 serial number was discovered and used by hackers (using a serial number generator). In that case, the serial number is black-listed in the Microsoft Activation database. However, if you can show proof of ownership, the Microsoft person on the phone could give you a replacement serial number.

If the problem is rather that you're using a Beta version of Windows 7, the best solution is to reformat the hard disk and install the Windows 7 release. Please note that any serial number you got with the Beta is no longer valid, so if that's the case, you'll need to buy the Windows 7 release.

Comment: @Harrymc - "I am getting a message that "This is not the genuie copy of Windows 7, please take backup of your data and upgrade it.". Is this the cause of the error? " (comments. Guess hes got an illegal copy or a RC version.)

Comment: @Shiki: The message text is wrong, so it's probably translated from another language, probably eastern. I'm adding some stuff how to recover from such errors, assuming that his version is legal.

Comment: @harrymc: Just wanted to 'warn' you before you put too much effort in it.. :) But yeah now its totally covering the issue

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure you were installing VS as an administrator? These sound like possible permissions issues

Comment: Thanks for response. :)
This is my home system and I have the admin rights.

Comment: I've found that a user account with admin privileges is not the same as the "Administrator" user account. For example, I recently installed VMware Server 2.x on Windows 7 and had to use the "Administrator" user account to change some folder locations; simply installing as my normal user account (which has admin rights) or using the "Run as Administrator" command wasn't sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming that to meet all of the system requirements([VS2008](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Support/),[SQL2005](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/system-requirements.aspx)) for the software. Here's my recommendation on the steps to take to get this to work. You should start from a fresh OS, but that's not required:

1. Uninstall any previous versions of VS or SQL.
2. Make sure that your OS has passed genuine validation. Activate the OS and run [windows update](http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com/) to prompt the genuine advantage validation. If you can download updates, you are valid.
3. Turn off UAC. You can't just turn down the slider, you have to actually turn it off all of the way. The only sure fire way is to modify the EnableLUA [registry setting](http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm) and reboot.
4. Run the installers.
5. Download and run any service packs or updates for both Visual Studio and SQL server. You should be able to use windows update for this, but you may have to hunt around the microsoft website for them. From what I can tell, SP2 for SQL server is required to get it working.
6. Reboot and try the software again. You can turn UAC back on once the install is done.

Hope that does it.